Refer citation with author name automatically in AMSRefs
MWE:

\documentclass{amsart}


\usepackage{hyperref,amsrefs}


\begin{document}
    \cite{hardy_wright_1938}, \ocite{hardy_wright_1938}
    
    \begin{bibdiv}
        \begin{biblist}
            \bib{hardy_wright_1938}{book}{ edition={4}, title={An introduction to the theory of numbers}, publisher={Oxford: Clarendon Press}, author={Hardy, G. H. and Wright, E. M.}, date={1960}}
        \end{biblist}
    \end{bibdiv}
\end{document}

Output:
I would like to get the output same as \textcite in biblatex, so that the citation yields  Hardy and Wright [1] instead of just [1]

With amsrefs is is not possible to achieve the result that you want. However you have two options to achieve similar results.
You can define a macro to to combine both author and year, and the a command to store the name of the author... manually, which is quite a pain in my opinion. But you can achieve that by following this MWE:
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsrefs}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\citewithauthor}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{bibauthor@#1}{%
    \cite{#1}%
  }{%
    \csname bibauthor@#1\endcsname~\cite{#1}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\setbibauthor}[2]{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname bibauthor@#1\endcsname{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\setbibauthor{hardy_wright_1938}{Hardy and Wright}

\begin{document}

    % Use the custom command
    \citewithauthor{hardy_wright_1938}

    \begin{bibdiv}
        \begin{biblist}
            \bib{hardy_wright_1938}{book}{
                edition={4}, 
                title={An introduction to the theory of numbers}, 
                publisher={Oxford: Clarendon Press}, 
                author={Hardy, G. H. and Wright, E. M.}, 
                date={1960}
            }
        \end{biblist}
    \end{bibdiv}

\end{document}

It achieves what you wanted, but yet again, it's the same that writing the author name before the normal \cite{...} command.

Other possibility, which does not have the same result as you except is to use the combination of author and year. As detailed in the documentation (refer to 6.2), it is possible to change the citation style to author-year to produce something like `(Hardy and Wright, 1960). To do so, just load the package with that option as following:
\usepackage[author-year]{amsrefs}

Hope it helped.
